# Can I connect to my Linux server using "Go > Connect to Server"?

Tags: unix

In Windows I use WinSCP. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using (S)FTP to connect to your server. Finder doesn't support SFTP and supports read-only access for FTP. You can use Terminal and the command line [SFTP client](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sftp.1.html), or you'll need to use a 3rd party app like [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) or [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/) to connect via FTP or SFTP.

The Finder supports [AFP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Filing_Protocol), [SMB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) (Windows file sharing), [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System), [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing), and probably a few others I'm forgetting via the *Connect to Server* window.

Details on supported protocols can be found in [Finder Help](https://help.apple.com/machelp/mac/10.10/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/mchlp1654)

Comment: Connect to Server does support FTP.

Comment: SSH file transfer protocols are SCP or SFTP, which (last I knew) are all that WinSCP supports. Hence the name, Windows Secure Copy. But you're right, The Finder will do standard FTP.

Comment: @Alex Finder does read-only FTP. You can use the command line sftp client

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [xdav](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV#Mac_OS_X) via a command like https://[your xdav server]

Alternatively I recommend [Expandrive](http://www.expandrive.com/) which works quite transparently as a mounted disc. (The only issue if the disc is large is the possible indexation by Spotlight)